# Unexpected characters on bulk insert with t-sql

Tags: t-sql

I'm using a report tool which , needs to load text files in sql. But I have a problem. I searched and I can't find an answer for this. I tried some ways but the problem exists.
All txt files are with utf encoding.

I'm using t-sql's bulk insert statement as exist.

```
IF OBJECT_ID ( 'dbo.tableName','U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.tableName
CREATE TABLE tableName ( line nvarchar(50) );
BULK INSERT dbo.tableName from 'file_with_path.txt'
WITH ( ROWTERMINATOR='\n' ) 
select * from dbo.tableName
```

And finally I'm getting these lines

[image]

(Sorry ! But I can't upload images. I haven't reputation :( )

What's wrong ?

Note : I tried as data type in the column also
varchar,text... But the result is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. The problem is from the openrowset which not supports utf-8.
I used directly bulk insert with temporary table and now I can read utf-8 encoded files without problem. Here is the code for people which maybe has the same problem

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
    lines nvarchar(max) NULL
)
BULK INSERT #temp
FROM 'c:\my\test.txt'
WITH(ROWTERMINATOR = '', CODEPAGE='65001')
SELECT * FROM #temp
DROP TABLE #temp
```

The codepage 65001 is the UTF-8
The file text.txt is with utf-encoding

Comment: what version of sql do you use? when I try it I get this: Msg 2775, Level 16, State 13, Line 5
The code page 65001 is not supported by the server.

Comment: Jayvee, I'm using the version 9.00.4035.00 , Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Standard Edition, Platform NT INTEL X86 with default server collation = "Greek_CI_AS"

Comment: Jayvee, Also your txt file must be utf-8. If u need you can send me an e-mail.

Comment: OK, that explains it. Because codepage='65001' was supported in SQL server 2005 but not in 2008 and later. I even tried it on SQL Server 2014 CTP2 and still not working. You need to be careful when you upgrade as this will stop working. https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/370419/

Answer (score 0):

try using ACP conversion:

```
BULK INSERT dbo.tableName from ''
WITH ( ROWTERMINATOR='\n',   CODEPAGE = 'ACP' )
```

Comment: Jayvee. Thank you for your reply. I tried it but it does not work. The same problem exists.

Comment: can you post a sample of the data file ?

Comment: OK. Here is the link for a sample file http://www.4shared.com/office/5T4IUOLfba/125929.html

Comment: sorry I can't download now but if you just paste here the first few lines as text, I'll try to reproduce the error

Comment: Jayvee, You can create a simple txt silfe with utf-8 encoding. Fill the file with some lines with numbers and then try to run the above query. Here is my first lines "
123" (without quotes)

Comment: ok, I think the problem is because SQL server doesn't support UTF-8: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx ; you may need to convert to ANSI or other supported code page before the bulk insert.

Comment: Thank you for all your replies. You are correct. Now I have another problem. I'm using Greek characters in txt files. SQL loads the file but in Chinese.. (char. problem). I preparing a new question

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22861217/openrowset-character-encoding-when-load-from-text-file